# People list of users in Google plus in android

Tags: android, google-plus

People list for a user was coming properly in my app... Suddenly I can see only few of them even the count is reduced.

I am using the following code to retrieve my people and then adding it to the list.

```
        try 
        {
            int count = personBuffer.getCount();

            Log.e("Count","Number"+count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_ID, personBuffer.get(i).getId());
                map.put(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME, personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                map.put(KEY_IMAGEPROFILE_URL, personBuffer.get(i).getImage().getUrl());

                personList.add(map);
            }

            adapter=new FriendsAdapter(this, personList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } 

        finally 
        {
            personBuffer.close();
        }
```

I have around 150 people in my circle but it is showing only 80.

can anybody tell what is wrong here? It was working fine couple of minutes back it has stopped working with very less people.

I am totally confused! :(

**Update:**

I am getting the following error now:

```
 08-04 17:27:23.409: W/GLSUser(629): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken() 
 08-04 17:27:23.635: W/GLSUser(629): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
 08-04 17:27:24.198: I/qtaguid(797): Failed write_ctrl(u 70) res=-1 errno=22
 08-04 17:27:24.198: I/qtaguid(797): Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-22
 08-04 17:27:24.198: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(797): untagSocket(70) failed with errno -22
 08-04 17:27:24.198: E/Volley(797): [126] tm.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?maxResults=100&orderBy=alphabetical&pageToken=103193341800315457743
```

Why is a maxResults=100?

PS: I have edited ID: 103193341800315457743

Thanks!

Comment: What is the body of the 400 respons? There should be an error.

Comment: I don't see this any other error. what do you mean by body of the 400 respnse!

Comment: 400 is the HTTP status code and indicates there is an error. The HTTP response body should have the reason for the error. You can see an example by just hitting execute on [this example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list?userId=me&collection=visible&_h=1&) without authenticating first. This example is a 403 error instead though.

Comment: Yep. That is the only error it should...

Comment: Is there limit to use Google Plus API?

Comment: @abraham : The sample project given my google is showing all friends. I am using the same code with few changes in UI. How come I can see only 100.

Comment: You can only see 100 because each request has a pagination limit. Use the nextPageToken to get the next 100 results.

Comment: @abraham where do I need to apply pagination token?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/#pagination

Comment: I have seen this, but how do I apply this with the code I have (shown in the question)..

Comment: I trying out this: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people